# Jetson Nano Unmet dependency after CUDA installation

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, package-management, dependencies, cuda

I have tried to install CUDA 11 on Jetson Nano 4G

```sh
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/sbsa/cuda-ubuntu1804.pin
‍
sudo mv cuda-ubuntu1804.pin /etc/apt/preferences.d/cuda-repository-pin-600
‍
wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/11.0.2/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local_11.0.2-450.51.05-1_arm64.deb
‍
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local_11.0.2-450.51.05-1_arm64.deb
‍
sudo apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-ubuntu1804-11-0-local/7fa2af80.pub
sudo apt-get update
‍
sudo apt-get -y install cuda
```

but after the last step I started to get the following error:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-drivers-450 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-450 (>= 450.51.05) but it is not installed
                    Depends: libnvidia-gl-450 (>= 450.51.05) but it is not installed
 libnvidia-decode-450 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-450 (= 450.51.05-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
 libnvidia-ifr1-450 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-450 but it is not installed
 nvidia-compute-utils-450 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-450 but it is not installed
 nvidia-driver-450 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-450 (= 450.51.05-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
                 Depends: libnvidia-compute-450 (= 450.51.05-0ubuntu1) but it is not installed
 nvidia-utils-450 : Depends: libnvidia-compute-450 but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

can you please tell me how can I solve it, as I have tried `apt --fix-broken install`, but it didn't work, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to force the installation to continue like this:

`sudo apt-get -o dpkg::Options::="--force-overwrite" install --fix-broken`